# How to create different keys for ReordableListView, in async enviroment?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create fake firebase, and i have problem with "key: ValueKey(index),". I am trying create elements in "ReorderableListView".

```
FutureBuilder<List<FirstListModel>>(
                  future: fakeFirebase.getList(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return snapshot.data != null
                        ? ReorderableListView.builder(
                            (some code)
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                                for (var item in snapshot.data!) {
                                  return buildPlate(index, item);
                                }
                              } else {
                                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                              }
                              throw Exception("Error I am Empty");
                            },
                          )
                        : const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                )
```

i am creating items for that ReorderableListView in floatingActionButton which is in my Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addWidget,
      ),
      (some code)
      body: Center(
          child: fakeFirebase.firstList.isNotEmpty
              ? FutureBuilder<List<FirstListModel>>(
```

this code is in my floatingActionButton:

```
void _addWidget() {
    lol++;
    final item = FirstListModel(text: lol.toString(), id: lol.toString());
    setState(() {
      fakeFirebase.addElement(item);
    });
  }
```

this place is my "key", which is creating my problems:

```
  Widget buildPlate(int index, FirstListModel oneElement) {
    return ListTile(
      key: ValueKey(index),
```

this is my model:

```
class FirstListModel {
  String text;
  String id;
  FirstListModel({
    required this.text,
    required this.id,
  });
}
```

right now i put in my "key" index, in hope it will not create an error, sadly when i press my floatingActionButton in order to add new elements it only shows meany times one element.
I want to create new elements that cen be edited and deleted, drag and droped, but i know this "key" is a reson that i am not able to do it, someon have a solution to my problem? if you need more code, i can provide it, i am creating this app to learn.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the actual item id instead of the index in the list to generate the `ValueKey`, like so: `ValueKey(oneElement.id)`?

Comment: yes, i tried, and it gives me an error. First it creates one element, but when i want to add more, app crash. I have error: "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey."

Comment: Have you verified that you are not adding two items with the same `ValueKey` sounds like some items are added multiple times.

Comment: well, i post answer, from what i know i whas creating list of list's ReordableListView where creating list by it own, and in there i had for loop, iterating again and again. I had return statement and it only gave me first element over and over gain. When i removed for, everything work, cuz ReordableListView's ItemBuilder where creating list by its own, i have answer here, below what whas wrong in code

Answer (score 0):

if someon find this problem, i found a solution:

i had problem in here:

```
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                                for (var item in snapshot.data!) {
                                  return buildPlate(index, item);
                                }
                              }
```

i needed to change this as follows:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              if (snapshot.data?[index] != null) {
                                return buildPlate(index, snapshot.data![index]);
                              } else {
                                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                              }
                              throw Exception("Error I am Empty");
                            },
```

now I have still a problems, but it is running

Comment: Please try with UniqueKey()

Comment: but how to call some randome UniqueKey()? i have a "ReorderableListView" so i need to know what i am refering to, i also want to add remove and edid buttons, so having UniqueKey() will give a random key, i do not thing it is good solution